# JavaFX - "Progress Window"

Tags: database, javafx, blob, progress-indicator

I would like to show a little "Progress Window", contained in a FXML while i put some big BLOBs in a Database.

The Problem is: The Window won't appear till the Insert is executed.

I thought maybe it would be the problem that the FXML loader is too "slow"?
And can't display the window because of that.

I also tried adding a ProgressIndicator directly into the FXML of my form and make it just visible when the action button is pressed.

Same thing - the `.setVisible` Method won't work until the Insert is done.

This is very very very hair-raising Problem for me.

I'm developing a Management Tool and I can't let the user insert a big File and give him no response if something is in Progress or not!?

Would be fine if anyone has a solution for this problem!

Best Thanks!

Comment: The DB operations should be done in another thread than JavaFX UI Thread. Otherwise the UI will wait/freeze temporarily until the DB task has been done. Investigate this [search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+or+%5Bjavafx-2%5D+progress+bar+task+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Well... Now it's gettin' complicated, I think... But thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... after the hint from Uluk Biy I started trying around.
After 6 hours I did the trick like this:

This is my Method, that returns the needed Task.

```
public static Task saveNewAccoounting(final Accounting a){
    Task<Integer> saveNewAccountingTask = new Task<Integer>() {
        @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {
            try {
                run.logger.log(Level.FINE, "Started saveNewAccounting Task!");
                PreparedStatement newAcc;
                      newAcc = Connect.con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `ACCOUNTING`(`ACCNUMBER`, `ACCDATE`, `SHOP`, `CUSTOMER`, `CATEGORIES`, `WRITTENBY`, `DATE`, `DESCRIPTION`, `NOTE`, `PRICE`, `FILEORIGINAL`, `FILEBYTE`) VALUES (null,null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                      newAcc.setInt(1, a.getShop());
                      newAcc.setInt(2, a.getCustomer());
                      newAcc.setInt(3, a.getCategories());
                      newAcc.setInt(4, Credentials.getUserid());
                      newAcc.setDate(5, a.getDate());
                      newAcc.setString(6, a.getDescription());
                      if (a.getNote().equals("")){
                        newAcc.setNull(7, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                      } else {
                        newAcc.setString(7, a.getNote());    
                      }
                      newAcc.setDouble(8, a.getPrice());
                      if(a.getAttachment() != null){
                          newAcc.setString(9, a.getAttachment().getName());
                          newAcc.setBlob(10, new FileInputStream(a.getAttachment()));
                      } else {
                          newAcc.setNull(9, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                          newAcc.setNull(10, java.sql.Types.BLOB);
                      }
                      if(!newAcc.execute()){
                          newAcc.close();
                          run.logger.log(Level.FINE, "Successfully completed saveNewAccounting Task!");
                          return 1;
                      } else {
                          newAcc.close();
                          run.logger.log(Level.FINE, "Completed saveNewAccounting Task with Failures!");
                          return 0;
                      }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                run.dblogger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
                run.logger.log(Level.FINE, "Completed saveNewAccounting Task with Failures!");
                return 0;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException f){
                run.iologger.log(Level.SEVERE, f.getMessage());
                run.logger.log(Level.FINE, "Completed saveNewAccounting Task with Failures!");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    };
   return saveNewAccountingTask;
}
```

All you have to do then is instantiate a Thread with the returned Task and execute it.

```
//Make your Progress visible here
final Task saveTask = SaveTasks.saveNewAccoounting(acc);
Thread saveThread = new Thread(saveTask);
saveThread.setDaemon(true);
saveThread.start();
```

Now add a Listener to the Task and stuff is done.

```
saveTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler() {
                   @Override
                    public void handle(Event t) {
                        Progress.close();
                        if (saveTask.getValue() == 1){
                            //SUCCESS
                        } else {
                            //FAIL
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Hope this will help somebody in future.